# For Btrfs, how to convert to DUP =3 or >3 on a single partition?

Tags: btrfs

**The question refers to:**

- Debian based Linux, kernel >=5.1
- explicitly also to systems with only one single harddisk or SSD, with only one Btrfs partition

**Hints on a possible implementation:**
"Will it be possible to use DUP for data as well as for metadata on a
single device?
And if so, am I going to be able to specify more than 1 copy of the data?"

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230328072455/https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/FiZGewd8/btrfs-data-dup-on-single-device

**Information on minimum supported profiles under Btrfs :**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230321174504/https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mkfs.btrfs.html#profiles

**Examples for the configuration of DUP=1:**.

Converting the metadata of an existing system with a single hard disk and a single partition, from DUP=2 to DUP=1:

```
btrfs balance start -mconvert=single / # convert metadata
btrfs balance start -dconvert=single / # convert data
```

**Examples for the configuration of DUP=2:**.

Converting the metadata of an existing system with a single hard disk and a single partition, from DUP=1 to DUP=2:

```
btrfs balance start -mconvert=dup / # convert metadata
btrfs balance start -dconvert=dup / # convert data
```

Its not asked for solutions which need more than one harddisk or more than one partition like p.e. the follow:

convert "single" without a redundancy to RAID1 with redundancy for data and metadata as follows:

```
btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1 /
```

convert "single" without a redundancy to RAID1c3 or RAID1c4

```
...
```

Comment: Hi Eddy! You've asked at least 11 questions and got 19 answers, but you have not accepted a single answer. This is a bit counterintuitive – I'm sure some of the answers have been good. Please fix that! This site only works if askers mark their questions as answered, and highlight correct answers.

Comment: No, thank you for keeping the site running :)

Comment: Could you explain what DUP>=3 is an why you believe it's possible.  The [user manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.btrfs.8.html) only refers to duplicating twice:
The mkfs utility will let the user create a filesystem with profiles that write the logical blocks to 2 physical locations.

Comment: Now I re-read it your [first link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230328072455/https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/FiZGewd8/btrfs-data-dup-on-single-device) asks a question of *"am I going to be able to specify more than 1 copy of the data?"* and a pretty firm response on the same email thread says *"It'll be exactly 2 copies at the moment."*. It seems there's a pretty firm response in your own links saying this won't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Btrfs currently does not provide a `DUP=3` or `DUP>3` profile. The supported profiles are listed [here](https://wiki.tnonline.net/w/Btrfs/Profiles)

There is no ambiguity, DUP has a space efficiency of 50%. Then you don’t have a DUP3 (which would mean 33% efficiency).

The closest of a DUP3 would be RAID1c3, but it needs 3 different block devices.

(If you don’t trust the linked page, use `man mkfs.btrfs`).

Comment: That dosnt fit the question.

Comment: You have asked for a DUP=3 or more, and I answer you the reference of the documentation which doesn't provide such a case. Then I don't think there would be an answer which perfectly fit the question, excepted perhaps a patch for the kernel and for the btrfs tools. But it would be too imature for a production server. I guess this woulnd't fit too.

Comment: Just writing anything is not a solution. If you don't know a solution, don't "answer". Sorry.

Comment: @Eddy763 this answer is not writing "just anything" it is telling you that you are searching for a way to use a feature that doesn't exist. it's telling you that it's impossible. Such answers are perfectly acceptable here and indeed [welcome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95764/should-one-accept-negative-answers/95817)

Comment: The answer is not only not fitting, the answer is also wrong. P.e a RAID1c3 can also run on 3 different partitions on same HD.

Comment: P.e.: 1`st: The "answer" don't offer a asked solution about DUP>=3 on one HD. 2`nd: Additional, the answer is wrong. RAID1c3 dosnt need 3 drives. Can run on 3 partitions on same drive also.

Comment: @Eddy763 **Your question** asks for a single partition. RAID cannot be used on a single partition. The fact this answer accidentally mentions "drives" instead of "partitions" is irrelevant.  You still can't setup a three way raid on a single partition.  There's no such thing as a three way DUP in BTRFS. I know you don't want to hear this, but you can't do the thing you are asking for, and this answer is correctly pointing that out! The minor error in terminology doesn't make the core of this answer incorrect. You can't do what you're asking for. Thats a fact.

Comment: ZFS Raid 5 p.e. can used on 3 disks, or 3 partitions on one disk or ON 3 FILES ON A SINGLE PARTITION.

Comment: But the question wasn't about ZFS. And I guess that using ZFS on different files uses different block devices anyway (loopN). (I havn't checked)

Comment: A answer like "I dont know a fitting answer" isnt a fitting answer.

Comment: @Eddy763 To be honest you are being pretty rude here. You asked a question and at least two of us have spent significant time researching it and both independently concluded that the thing you want is **demonstrably impossible**. Nobody has said "I don't know", this answer certainly doesn't imply that. and it is quite rude of you to characterise it this way.

Comment: @Alfred.37 RAIDc3 doesn't even need 3 partitions. It can run on any 3 block devices. These can be derived from the single partition you want to use, e.g. via LVM, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot re-partition your disk, there are a number of options for obtaining 3 block devices of equal size from a single partition that then can be used together with btrfs and a `raid1c3` profile. Options:

- LVM: Make your current partition the sole PV of a new LVM volume group and create 3 volumes of equal size on it. Use these volumes to create a new btrfs filesystem with `raid1c3` profile.
- mdadm: create an mdadm device, e.g. `/dev/md0`, from the partition with `linear`, `raid0` or `raid1` mode and options `-n 1 --force`, then partition the device and create a btrfs filesystem from the nested partitions, e.g. `/dev/md0p1`, `/dev/md0p2` and `/dev/md0p3`.
- bcache: create  a bcache device using the partition as a backing device (it's fine to run with no cache) and create partitions on the bcache device; create a btrfs filesystem on the new partitions, e.g.  `/dev/bcache0p1`, `/dev/bcache0p2` and `/dev/bcache0p3` (for the partition device files to appear, I had to issue a command last time I tried this; they should appear automatically on the next reboot)

Having a backup is advised and the mdadm and bcache options probably require storing the data temporarily somewhere else, i.e. creating the mdadm or bcache device is destructive. For the LVM option, you can shrink your current btrfs filesystem and follow my answer "manual lvmify" to https://superuser.com/questions/493481/fastest-way-to-convert-an-ext4-formatted-disk-to-lvm-with-ext4-on-it to convert the partition to a logical volume. (The accepted answer uses a tool that includes the shrinking step but it set the size not small enough for your purposes.)

If your partition is on an SSD with internal deduplication you may want to add a LUKS layer so the SSD sees different data for each copy and is forced to store each copy separately. Still, the timing of writing each copy may mean that the copies end up in the same storage block and the probability of all copies failing simultaneously may be higher than expected.

For `raid1c4` adjust above suggestions to create 4 devices instead of 3.